# Is it possible to get the name of specialized class from a static method in an abstract class?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I am looking for a way to get the name of **specialized** class from a **static** method in an **abstract class** ?

Comment: You can't. What would you use it for? You could do that from a non-static method, but not from a static one.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You mean a static method that somehow overrides another one? That's not even supported in Java. You can only get the class that declares the static method if you have a `Method` handle. Any static method with the same signature in a subclass is not an override but hides the subclass method, much like "redefined" fields do.

Comment: Only if you pass an object instance to the static method - but then you could have implemented it as an instance method as well.

Comment: For my tests, I have a base test class (the abstract class). The name of the database is depend on the name of concretes classes.

Comment: I found another solution, I avoid static method then I use the constructor of my classes to set fields.